# How does Perl match annotation "//" for verilog files?

Tags: regex, perl

I have found one method, but I don't understand the principle:

```
#remove lines starting with //

$file =~ s/(?<=\n)[ \t]*?\/\/.*?\n//sg;
```

How does `(?<=\n)[ \t]*?` work?

Comment: Perl comes with a manual.  The page you need is [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The critical piece is the [lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) `(?<=...)`.  It is a *zero-width assertion*, what means that it does not consume its match -- it only asserts that the pattern given inside is indeed in the string, right before the pattern that follows it.

So `(?<=\n)[ \t]` matches either a space or a tab, `[ \t]`, that has a newline before it. With the quantifier, `[ \t]*`, it matches a space-or-tab any number of times (possibly zero).  Then we have the `//` (each escaped by `\`). Then it matches any character any number of times up to the first newline, `.*?\n`.

Here `?` makes `.*` non-greedy so that it stops at *the first* match of the following pattern.

This can be done in other ways, too.

```
$file =~ s{ ^ \s* // .*? \n }{}gmx
```

The modifier `m` makes anchors `^` and `$` (unused here) match the beginning and end of each *line*. I use `{}{}` as delimiters so that I don't have to escape `/`. The modifier `x` allows use of spaces (and comments and newlines) inside for readability.

You can also do it by [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)-ing the string by newline and passing lines through [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

```
my $new_file = join '\n', grep { not m|^\s*//.*| } split /\n/, $file;
```

The `split` returns a list of lines and this is input for `grep`, which passes those for which the code in the block evaluates to true.  The list that it returns is then joined back, if you wish to again have a multiline string.
If you want lines remove `join '\n'` and assign to an array instead.

The regex in the `grep` block is now far simpler, but the whole thing may be an eye-full in comparison with the previous regex.  However, this approach can turn hard jobs into easy ones: instead of going for a monster master regex, break the string and process the pieces easily.

Comment: Lazy quantifier as well as newline character in `.*? \n` don't make sense. You may safely remove them.

Comment: @revo The `\n` must be there since it need be _removed_ from the string (otherwise I keep blank lines).  I can indeed remove `?` here, which is how I had it originally. But that requires an explanation (involved for this purpose), since it belongs there in principle. So I thought it better to leave it.